# What will Lubavitchers do in 2052?

Tags: calendar, chabad, tehilim-psalms, chassidic-rebbe

There's a Chabad-Lubavitch custom of reciting a psalm of *T'hilim* corresponding to one's age. That is, for example, in one's fourteenth year of life (e.g. on his thirteenth birthday), he says the fourteenth psalm. (I'm not sure whether it's recited only on one's birthday or throughout the year. But that's immaterial for my purposes.)

The *Luach Kolel Chabad* says that this year (5775)'s eleventh of  *Nisan* would have been the last Lubavitcher rebbe's 113th birthday, so everyone should say the 114th psalm on that day.

*T'hilim* has 150 psalms. What will Lubavitchers do in the year 5812, on the rebbe's 150th birthday?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start again from alef (1). There are chassidim who say the chapter  for earlier rebbeim also (eg. on that Rebbe's birthday), and they start again from alef. This is what I see people doing, though I'm not sure if there's any documented source for it.

Comment: This accords with the practice of reciting a chapter of Baati L'Gani (the Previous Rebbe's last talk) on Yud Shvat.  The first year they recited Chapter 1.  When they reached the end (within the most recent Rebbe's lifetime), they started again.  This has happened again since.