# Source for Tehillim of your age?

Tags: minhag, tehilim-psalms, age

Does anybody know of a source for the minhag to recite daily the perek of tehillim corresponding to your age?

Comment: welcome to Mi Yodeya LMR thanks to you I discovered this minhag. Good question

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56735/759

Comment: LMR welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for the interesting question! I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Comment: Chabad is the source for this Minhag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a custom transmitted from the Maggid of Mezritch to the Alter Rebbe of Lubavitch in the name of the Ba'al Shem Tov.

This is recorded in a letter of the Previous Lubavitcher Rebbe, printed in the back of תהלים אהל יוסף יצחק. In [this print](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32596&st=&pgnum=214&hilite=) it is on page 214.

The full letter is printed in Vol 10 of his letters, [page 53](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31697&st=&pgnum=80&hilite=).

The reason for the custom is cryptically described by the Alter Rebbe [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33086&st=&pgnum=365&hilite=) (מאמרי אדה"ז הקצרים page 341), which is somewhat explained by the most recent Lubavitcher Rebbe [here](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/29/33).